# Pusher Beam stop private notifications but keep public notifications

Tags: javascript, php, pusher

I have a website with a Public Blog and Private Backend. Logged in or not, the user can decide to receive browser notifications about the Blog, which is an *interest* https://pusher.com/docs/beams/getting-started/web/sdk-integration#subscribe-to-an-interest

**This works great**

```
const beamsClient = new PusherPushNotifications.Client(
{
    instanceId: '...'
});

beamsClient.start().then(() => beamsClient.addDeviceInterest('Blog'));
```

If he answer "Yes" to the notifications, Pusher will save his `DeviceId` and thats fine. Now, when ther logs in into my Private Backend, he will be able to receive notifications directly to him https://pusher.com/docs/beams/guides/publish-to-specific-user/web.

**This also works great**

```
const beamsTokenProvider = new PusherPushNotifications.TokenProvider(
{ 
    url: '...' 
});

const beamsClient = new PusherPushNotifications.Client(
{
    instanceId: '...'
});

beamsClient.start().then(() => beamsClient.setUserId('MY_USER_ID', beamsTokenProvider));
```

**The problem:**

When the user decides to logout, I delete his authenticated device from the Pusher Beam (https://pusher.com/docs/beams/reference/server-sdk-php#-deleteuser) and my objective is only to stop him from receiving Private Authenticated Notifications, but it is removing completly his device from Pusher, which means the Public Blog Notifications no longer works.

The description of the function `deleteUser` is explicit:

> Remove the given user (and all of their devices) from Beams. This user
> will no longer receive any notifications and all state stored about
> their devices will be deleted.

From the moment I delete the user, I start receiving in the console:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unexpected status code 404: Not found,
> Device not found

How do I stop Private Notifications but keep Public Notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

Instead of using the `deleteUser` PHP function, I have to use the `clearAllState` JS function when logging out.
https://pusher.com/docs/beams/reference/web#-clearallstate

> Clears all the state in the SDK, leaving it in a empty started state.
> You should call this method when your user logs out of the
> application.

This way only the Private Notifications are cleared and the Public Notificatons remain active.